# On click slidding out the current content and slide in a new one

Tags: jquery, html

Hi and thank you for your time.

I have a nav bar and couple of DIVs. When button is clicked i want to slide current DIV to the left and out of the page and slide in new DIV from the right.

[http://www.wix.com/website-template/view/html/1634?originUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wix.com%2Fwebsite%2Ftemplates%2Fhtml%2Fall%2F13&bookName=&galleryDocIndex=2&category=all][1]

I saw it on this page and just want to learn how it is done. I know how to use jquery and onClick animate it to the left and fadeout but cant return it to home position a set it ready to be clicked again.

So if there is some example how to do it or if there is some tutorial please let me know. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve the effect found in the site you provided. Below is one implementation using JQuery and CSS.

Note that the JQuery used here has not been abbreviated so that the function logic is exposed, but you can definitely shorten the code once you've familiarized yourself with it.

```js
 

//the "slideIn" and "slideOut" classes being added are CSS animations. Please refer to the CSS code.
$('.menu').click(function(){
   $('.current').removeClass('slideIn slideOut').addClass('slideOut').delay(100).removeClass('current');
});
   
$('.first').click(function(){
  $('.slide-1').delay(100).addClass('slideIn').fadeIn().delay(200).addClass('current');
});

$('.second').click(function(){
  $('.slide-2').delay(100).addClass('slideIn').fadeIn().delay(200).addClass('current');
});

$('.third').click(function(){
  $('.slide-3').delay(100).addClass('slideIn').fadeIn().delay(200).addClass('current');
});

$('.fourth').click(function(){
  $('.slide-4').delay(100).addClass('slideIn').fadeIn().delay(200).addClass('current');
});
```

```css
.menu {
  float:left;
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid black;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.content {
  position:fixed;
  width:80%;
  margin-left:10%;  
  background:red;
  height:70px;
  margin-top:100px;
  display:none;
  text-align:center;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:white;
  padding-top:30px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.slideOut {
  animation: slideOut .7s forwards;
}
.slideIn {
  animation: slideIn 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes slideOut {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity:1;
  }
  80% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-80%);
opacity:0;
  }
}

@keyframes slideIn {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(80%);
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity:1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu first">
First!
</div>
<div class="menu second">
Second!
</div>
<div class="menu third">
Third!
</div>
<div class="menu fourth">
Fourth!
</div>

<div class="content slide-1">
First Div Here!
</div>
<div class="content slide-2">
Second Div Here!
</div>
<div class="content slide-3">
Third Div Here!
</div>
<div class="content slide-4">
Fourth Div Here!
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for. Thank you Sir from the bottom of my heart :)

Comment: Great! Would you mind accepting my answer then? Thanks,

Comment: Sorry mate. I just copy it to try it and it doesn't work. I use sublime text 2 and it doesn't recognize nothing below css transition. Do i need to do anything special to work.

Comment: Can you make sure that you are loading your JQuery library properly? This is a common issue that's overlooked in a lot of cases.

Comment: Jq was ok, somehow i made it work. Thank you for everything. You helped me alot :)